# bootstrap not working in JSFiddle

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, jsfiddle

I'm missing something extremely basic but I can't get this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/94zh1zgj/1/) to work with bootstraps `col-md-x`. How can I get the column spacing to work properly and not skip lines? Bootstrap appears to be loading properly

```
<div ng-app>
  <div class="container" ng-controller="TodoCtrl">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-1">.col-md-1</div>
    <div class="col-md-1">.col-md-1</div>
    <div class="col-md-1">.col-md-1</div>
    <div class="col-md-1">.col-md-1</div>
    <div class="col-md-1">.col-md-1</div>
    <div class="col-md-1">.col-md-1</div>
    <div class="col-md-1">.col-md-1</div>
    <div class="col-md-1">.col-md-1</div>
    <div class="col-md-1">.col-md-1</div>
    <div class="col-md-1">.col-md-1</div>
    <div class="col-md-1">.col-md-1</div>
    <div class="col-md-1">.col-md-1</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

it works fine. you are using `col-md-*` which is too big for the jsfiddle's small screen. just resize the output screen or replace `col-md-*` by `col-xs-*`